# SQL Select Statement Max Payment Date for Each Vendor Sub Query

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, max, multiple-tables

I am definitely a SQL newb so maybe you guys can help me understand something and potentially help with a solution to what I think must be an easy problem.

I run this query and it returns results that I want and feel are correct.

```
SELECT distinct 
   isnull(T3.[name],'') [Vendor Name]
  ,T1.[active] [Active]
  ,T1.[number] [Vendor Number]
  ,T1.[mnemonic] [Mnemonic]
  ,T1.[bank_acc] [Bank Account]
  ,isnull(T1.[our_acct_number],'') [Our Account Number]
  ,isnull(T1.[fed_id_num],'') [Fed ID]
  ,isnull((select  T2.[ap_contact_name] [AP Contact] from TABLE2 T2 
  where [ap_contact] = '1' and T2.[number] = T1.[number]),'') [AP Contact]
  ,isnull(T2.[ap_contact_phone],'') [Contact Phone Number]
  ,isnull(T1.[print_1099],'') [Print 1099?]
  ,isnull(T1.[expense_type],'') [Expense Type]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_1],'') [Remit Street Address]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_2],'') [Other Adress Info]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_3],'') [Remit City, State, Zip]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_1099], '') [Remit 1099?] 


FROM 
TABLE1 T1
LEFT outer JOIN
TABLE2 T2
ON T1.[number] = T2.[number]
left outer join
TABLE3 T3
ON T1.[number] = T3.[number]
left outer join
TABLE4 T4
on T1.[number] = T4.[number]
left join
TABLE5 T5
ON T1.[number] = T5.[txn_vendor]
LEFT join
TABLE6 T6
ON T5.[txn_inv_num] = T6.[inv_num]


 WHERE
 T1.[active] ='Y'

 order by 
[Vendor Name]
```

However, when I add this subquery to the select statement to return the last pay date for each vendor

```
 ,(SELECT
                 MAX(T6.[inv_date])
                 FROM
                Table6 T6
                WHERE

               T5.[txn_inv_num] = T6.[inv_num]
               group by T5.[txn_vendor],T5.[txn_inv_num]
                 )
                 [Last Pymt Date]
```

I get results with about 20 rows of duplicate vendors and different dates. I am trying to add the last payment date for each vendor to the result set.

I've also tried using a virtual table other ways but I am having no luck. Any input is appreciated.

Using SQL server 2008.

Comment: Could you try removing `,T5.[txn_inv_num]` from your `GROUP BY`

Comment: Yields the same unwanted results (too many records, duplicate vendors). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What do you get when you just run the subquery on it's own (with the `where` clause removed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `distinct` use `group by`.  Here is one version of your query, just changing the `distinct` to a `group by` and adding `max()` for the date:

```
SELECT distinct 
   isnull(T3.[name],'') [Vendor Name]
  ,T1.[active] [Active]
  ,T1.[number] [Vendor Number]
  ,T1.[mnemonic] [Mnemonic]
  ,T1.[bank_acc] [Bank Account]
  ,isnull(T1.[our_acct_number],'') [Our Account Number]
  ,isnull(T1.[fed_id_num],'') [Fed ID]
  ,isnull((select  T2.[ap_contact_name] [AP Contact] from TABLE2 T2 
  where [ap_contact] = '1' and T2.[number] = T1.[number]),'') [AP Contact]
  ,isnull(T2.[ap_contact_phone],'') [Contact Phone Number]
  ,isnull(T1.[print_1099],'') [Print 1099?]
  ,isnull(T1.[expense_type],'') [Expense Type]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_1],'') [Remit Street Address]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_2],'') [Other Adress Info]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_3],'') [Remit City, State, Zip]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_1099], '') [Remit 1099?],
  max(t6.inv_date) as [Last Pymt Date]


FROM 
TABLE1 T1
LEFT outer JOIN
TABLE2 T2
ON T1.[number] = T2.[number]
left outer join
TABLE3 T3
ON T1.[number] = T3.[number]
left outer join
TABLE4 T4
on T1.[number] = T4.[number]
left join
TABLE5 T5
ON T1.[number] = T5.[txn_vendor]
LEFT join
TABLE6 T6
ON T5.[txn_inv_num] = T6.[inv_num]


 WHERE
 T1.[active] ='Y'

group by
   isnull(T3.[name],'') [Vendor Name]
  ,T1.[active] [Active]
  ,T1.[number] [Vendor Number]
  ,T1.[mnemonic] [Mnemonic]
  ,T1.[bank_acc] [Bank Account]
  ,isnull(T1.[our_acct_number],'') [Our Account Number]
  ,isnull(T1.[fed_id_num],'') [Fed ID]
  ,isnull((select  T2.[ap_contact_name] [AP Contact] from TABLE2 T2 
  where [ap_contact] = '1' and T2.[number] = T1.[number]),'') [AP Contact]
  ,isnull(T2.[ap_contact_phone],'') [Contact Phone Number]
  ,isnull(T1.[print_1099],'') [Print 1099?]
  ,isnull(T1.[expense_type],'') [Expense Type]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_1],'') [Remit Street Address]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_2],'') [Other Adress Info]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_addr_3],'') [Remit City, State, Zip]
  ,isnull(T4.[remit_1099], '') [Remit 1099?] 


 order by 
[Vendor Name]
```

Comment: Wow it was that easy. Thanks for your help!